# How do I launch a PHP Process in a Screen session that has not been invoked yet?

Tags: linux, daemon, gnu-screen

I want to launch a PHP Process in a Screen session that has not been invoked yet.  I do not want to attach to this screen.  I will be launching lots of these, by hand at first, then probably with a shell script.  I would like to write the output of each to a unique log file ( preferably in /tmp/shell ), but it really doesn't matter where.

This seems close to what I want, but doesn't work:

```
screen -d -m -X 'php process.php param1 param2'
```

**SOLUTION**

Just remove the -X.

This works `screen -d -m php process.php param1 param2`

Comment: Does anything here answer your question? http://serverfault.com/questions/104668/create-screen-and-run-command-without-attaching

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to skip `-X`:

```
screen -d -m 'php process.php param1 param2'
```

It's also useful to give the session a name, especially if you're starting several:

```
screen -d -m -S mysession 'php process.php param1 param2'
```

`-X` is for sending [commands](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#Command-Index) to `screen` itself.

See also: [this QA here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21191061/capture-ncurses-shell-output-in-php/21192362#21192362)

**Additional explanation**

The started `screen` session will only exist as long as your command is running. When `php process.php ...` exits, `screen` will also exit.

Comment: `screen -d -m` creates a new Screen session, but obviously doesn't start anything in it.  `screen -d -m 'php process.php param1 param2'` fails to start a new Screen session for me.  The command executes without any output.

Comment: @T.BrianJones - Maybe some problem running php. Try another command, like `screen -d -m top`, then `screen -r` and `top` should already be running. I use this all the time.

Comment: @T.BrianJones - If `php` exits, `screen` will also exit. Example: `screen -d -m date` will exit immediately so cannot be resumed.

Comment: I was mistaken.  This works fine for PHP processes ... `screen -d -m php process.php`